# Fancybox and minify - incorrect path for images

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, fancybox, minify

I just installed and started using fancybox to display my images and I'm having a hard-time making it work with minify.

First, minify didn't accept the `?v=2.1.5` when adding the `css` and `js`.

Now, fancybox's images are not loading, because for some reason (my guess: minify's fault) it is looking, incorrectly, for them at the root of my webserver.

My setup is this:

```
Root: http://localhost/arvores
Minify at: http://localhost/arvores/min
CSS files at: http://localhost/arvores/css
JS files at: http://localhost/arvores/js
```

Here's my .htaccess file for the root (/arvores):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt|javascript|js|files|icons|images)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /arvores/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I'm using Minify's group feature, so all my files are loaded with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/arvores/min/g=image_view_js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/arvores/min/g=image_view_css"/>
```

Problem is, as Chrome shows, it is looking for fancybox's images at `http://localhost/css/whateverimg.gif`

Any ideas?

Comment: all fancybox images (load icon, sprite png, etc) should be place under the same directory where placed the fancybox css file (`http://localhost/arvores/css` as in your setup)

Comment: They are, but they are getting called as `localhost/css` and I don't know why.

Comment: didn't you edit/modify the fancybox css file?

Comment: Nope, didn't even open it.
If I do `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />` it works fine, but if I Minify it, by open the css along with the other css files like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/arvores/min/g=image_upload_css"/>` then the path gets screwed up, and I can't find a way to fix this. :(